# How to interpret user supplied function using Shap (Shapley Additive explanation)?

Tags: python, shap

I want to use the python Shap module to interpret user supplied nonlinear functions. I'll take just one simple example as a representative, but it cannot run successfully. I would like to ask if Shap can be used for this simple model and if yes how to implement it.

Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import shap

def f(x):
        y = x[0] ** 2.5 + 3 * x[1] + 10
        return np.array(y)
x = np.arange(20).reshape((2, 10))

explainer = shap.Explainer(f)
shap_values = explainer(x)
```

Below are the error messages

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\PYCHARM\lib\site-packages\shap\explainers\_permutation.py", line 74, in __call__
    return super().__call__(
  File "E:\PYCHARM\lib\site-packages\shap\explainers\_explainer.py", line 258, in __call__
    row_result = self.explain_row(
  File "E:\PYCHARM\lib\site-packages\shap\explainers\_permutation.py", line 132, in explain_row
    outputs = fm(masks, zero_index=0, batch_size=batch_size)
  File "E:\PYCHARM\lib\site-packages\shap\utils\_masked_model.py", line 64, in __call__
    return self._full_masking_call(full_masks, zero_index=zero_index, batch_size=batch_size)
  File "E:\PYCHARM\lib\site-packages\shap\utils\_masked_model.py", line 93, in _full_masking_call
    masked_inputs = self.masker(mask, *self.args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean this: 10 datapoints, 2 features, 1 outcome?

```
import numpy as np
from shap import KernelExplainer


def f(x):
    y = x[:, 0] ** 2.5 + 3 * x[:, 1] + 10
    return np.array(y)


x = np.arange(20).reshape((10,2))
explainer = KernelExplainer(f, x)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your timely and professional feedback. Your reply perfectly solved my problem. Kind wishes. @Sergey Bushmanov